CORS on a single endpoint
I need your opinion and help with this problem I'm facing. I have an ASP.NET Core Web API. From a web app that consumes this API, there is an endpoint, and I emphasize ONE ENDPOINT, that causes a CORS error. And this only happens in production, it doesn't happen in development and testing/certification environments.
CORS policies are defined globally and the web domain is among the allowed origins.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at https://dominio-api.produccion.net/api/ParameMessages from origin https://dominio.produccion.net has been blocked by CORS policy: NoAccess-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. /#/administracion/parametros-lista:1 C
\> PUT https://dominio-api.produccion.net/api/ParameMessages net :: ERR_FAILED 403 (Forbidden)        polyfills.d2ee36b is:1

I tried at the controller level to set the CORS policy, and moved the UseCors middleware between routing and authentication:
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",

        builder => builder
            .WithOrigins
            (
                "http://localhost:4200",
                "https://dominio.produccion.net",
                "https://dominio.test.net"                
            )
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
        );
});

---

app.UseExceptionless();            

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseRateLimiter();


simple fix would be to keep everything same-domain.  Why not put the API at
dominio.produccion.net/api?  ( If you must keep them separate domains, try installing CORS module... so on dominio-api.produccion.net try installing: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module  That should allow OPTIONS verb )

The problem is not CORS but 403, first fix the forbidden error, it is the browser that shows the Cors error.

CORS errors can be misleading sometimes. Even if the error in the API is not CORS related, but instead a server error (500) or in your case a forbidden error (403).
This happens because the browser sees the preflight (OPTIONS) request failed, then it will say it is a CORS error.
Seeing that you already have the proper headers setup through the options.AddPolicy(), I would suggest checking why the API respond with a 403 status.
